# search for a word in entire table - MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, select

Currently am using the following code for search for a word in the entire table,

```
    Dim searchKey As String = "Sample"
    Dim mysql As String = "SELECT * FROM myTable " & _
                          "WHERE col1 LIKE '%" & searchKey & "%' " & _
                          " OR col2 LIKE '%" & searchKey & "%' " & _
                          " OR col3 LIKE '%" & searchKey & "%' " & _
                          " OR col4 LIKE '%" & searchKey & "%' "
```

But querying became more difficult when the *number of column increases*. so can anyone suggest me some alternative method for do the same.

Comment: use a loop to build your String

Comment: how to loop col name will be different in each row na?

Comment: you can add col names to array ,and loop will make your String .see my answer

Answer (score 0):

use a loop to build your String programmatically .in this example you only need to add your columns to array.

```
Dim searchKey As String = "Sample"
Dim array() As String = {"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"}
Dim b As Boolean = True

Dim mysql As String = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE "

For Each str As String In array
    If b Then
        mysql = mysql & str + " LIKE '%" & searchKey & "%'"
    Else
        mysql = mysql & " OR " & str & " LIKE '%" & searchKey & "%'"
    End If
    b = False

Next

Debug.WriteLine(mysql)
```

output>>

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 LIKE '%Sample%' OR col2 LIKE '%Sample%' OR col3 LIKE '%Sample%' OR col4 LIKE '%Sample%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also take help of the fulltext search provided by MySQL.
This link provides details on fulltext search, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, If there is change in table structure then you need to add/remove columns from the query.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Concat(col1, '',col2, '', coln) LIKE '%searchKey%'
```

Comment: @NeethuSoman, it works. I have tested it on my local machine. Can you show me how you did it?

Comment: interesting... it should work. Have you tried it on database directly?
Also interesting thing is that you are not using myTable anywhere in your query then why it is throwing error 'FUNCTION myTable.concat does not exist'.